# Integrating third party tool

Tags: android, ios, swift

this may be a simple question but i really want to know. When building an app, what is the cons of using a third party tool, for example photobrowsers, side menu or etc. The pros are of course, easy to implement and less headache to do on own but what about the cons?

let's take a scenario, if company ABC made an app and used many third party tools. One day it expanded and became a big company, will it face legal issues from using them?

Comment: This is more of a discussion topic than a "question". But I understand it's sometimes hard for new devs, so I wanted to give you some feedback still. Pros of frameworks are that you can bring in features built by pros, you can speed up development, and you can focus your energy on the core functions of the app. The cons are that you may not fully understand what code is running your app, this makes things harder to troubleshoot and fix and can leave you open to vulnerabilities. They can also lead to unnecessarily large and bloated projects. Best wishes!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you adhere to the licenses etc. of tools or libraries you consume, legal matters should not enter into the equation.  It's rare that companies get anywhere by suing those who [use their products as intended](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_America,_Inc._v._Google,_Inc.).

I usually see it as both the pro and the con is "you didn't build it yourself".  On the plus side it's work you didn't have to do and don't need to maintain. On the minus, you can't control  what it is: it's not purpose-built for your use case and may not exactly match what you need.